# In my Ubuntu18, by mistake i have deleted python folders from /usr/lib ? If i run command "sudo apt-get install --reinstall python" then not working

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

**This is what i got after sudo apt-get install --reinstall python**

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.15~rc1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3-gi (= 3.26.1-2ubuntu1) but 3.26.1-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Sooo... have you tried the `apt --fix-broken install` it asked you to do?

Comment: Yes. It says 
Preparing to unpack .../python3-gi_3.26.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Comment: this question should be part of [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)